# How do I de-couple frame reading from frame processing?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, opencv

I wrote some image analysis in OpenCV's Python API. Images are acquired in real-time from a webcam with the `read()` function of a `cv2.VideoCapture` object within a `while True` loop.

Processing a frame takes about 100ms. My camera would be capable of providing 30 fps. But if I even try to set its FPS to 15 my slow processing will lead to increasing lag. The processing happens on frames that get older and older in relation to "now". I can only run in real-time if I set the FPS to 5 which is a bit low. I assume incoming frames are buffered and once my loop returns to the start, the next frame is read from that buffer instead of straight from the camera.

I read elsewhere that running the frame grabbing and the processing in seperate threads would be the solution but I never used threading. Maybe I could get the most recent frame from the buffer instead?

I am using Python 3. I would prefer a OpenCV 3 answer if that is relevant, will accept a OpenCV 2 solution happily too.